# How do I loop through array of values posted

Tags: php, http-post

I'm posting an array of ids and want to loop over those values. I'm trying the following to populate an array with key/value pairs but it looks like the array is coming out empty.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id)
{
   $arr[$id] = GetStuff($id);
}
```

**UPDATE:** Looks like array was populated fine. I'm trying to return contents of array by doing `echo json_encode($arr)` but response is blank.

Here is output of var_dump($_POST);

```
  array(1) {
  ["ids"]=>
  array(18) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "156795"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "156800"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "4292"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "796053"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "660520"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "4293"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "4287"
    [7]=>
    string(6) "488339"
    [8]=>
    string(6) "837701"
    [9]=>
    string(7) "1152093"
    [10]=>
    string(7) "1186434"
    [11]=>
    string(7) "1324432"
    [12]=>
    string(6) "796051"
    [13]=>
    string(6) "144860"
    [14]=>
    string(5) "15065"
    [15]=>
    string(7) "1324434"
    [16]=>
    string(5) "13066"
    [17]=>
    string(4) "6969"
  }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". The code is O.K. for this purpose, how do you send the array? Can you give us a var_dump($_POST);?

Comment: Do you have $_POST[ids] or $_POST['ids'] in your code?

Comment: sorry. updated my question with more details

Comment: Scoutman, I see you point, but this doesn't explain the error as PHP will fallback to the string 'ids' (still, it should be 'ids' in the code).

Comment: my apologies, i didn't copy code verbatim. i do have single quotes around ids in $_POST['ids'].   so that is not the issue.

Comment: dev.e.loper, please give the output of var_dump($_POST);

Comment: What does GetStuff() do?

Comment: @bozdos GetStuff() just returns a string

Comment: @halfdan updated question with var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @dev.e.loper: In that case your code will perfectly work. Please post GetStuff(), the error must be in there.

Comment: Sorry it looks like array is populated. The problem seems to be when I try to write a response by doing echo json_encode($arr);  the response is empty. I guess that was issue all along. Sorry guys :(

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST['ids'] AS $i=>$id) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Don't forget about quotes..

Comment: my apologies, i didn't copy code verbatim. i do have single quotes around ids in $_POST['ids']. so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id)
{
   $arr[$id] = GetStuff($id);
}
```

Notice the tick marks around ids in $_POST.

Comment: my apologies, i didn't copy code verbatim. i do have single quotes around ids in $_POST['ids']. so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id)
{
   $arr[$id] = $_POST['ids'][$id];
}
```

or even faster, if you are just wanting an array identical to the posted ids:

```
$arr = $_POST['ids'];
```

unless I am misunderstanding the question.